# Adding a Script to HTML returns errors

Tags: javascript, html, json, module, script-tag

I have this script 'a.js':

```js
import * as assets from '../assets/b.json';

async function loadData() {
  ...
}
```

b.json:

```json
[
  {...},
  {...}
]
```

I try to add this Script to my HTML but I get this error when I put `type="module"`.

```html
<script type="module" src="../scripts/a.js"></script>

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

And when I don't put `type="module"` I get this error

```html
<script src="../scripts/a.js"></script>

Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I've been stuck on this error for a while and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> import * as assets from '../assets/b.json';
> ```

It looks like there are two issues here.

1. The server says this is HTML so either:

   - Your URL is wrong (this is most likely and you should debug it by using the Network tab of the browser's developer tools to see what body and Content-Type header are on the response)
   - Your server is configured to claim that `.json` files are HTML and not JSON
2. Support for [JSON modules](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-modules) in web browsers is very weak.

   - Not supported in [Chrome](http://crbug.com/1132413) in 2022
   - Not supported in [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1670176) in 2022
   - Not supported in [Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=228307) in 2022

Comment: Yes, the problem was the JSON, thank you